# Sorting collection array

Tags: laravel, sorting, lumen

Can anybody help how to sort the keys in a collection?

I tried using `sort()` function however it didn't work.

**Current implementation:**
public function myFunction($param)
    {
        $collectionOne = collect();

```
    foreach ($param as $keyOne=> $valueOne) {
      $collectionTwo = collect();

      foreach ($valueOne as $id) {

          $result= $this->model()::find($id);

          if (!isset($result) || empty($result)) throw new NoRecordFoundException('Not Found');

          $resultId = $result->some_id;

          if ($collectionTwo->has($resultId)) {
              $collectionTwo[$resultId]->push($id);
          } else {
              $collectionThree= collect($id);
              $collectionTwo->put($resultId, $collectionThree);
          }
      }

      $collectionOne->put($keyOne, $collectionTwo->sort());
      var_dump($collectionTwo->toArray());
    }
    return $collectionOne;
}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
MyRepository.php:124:
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 4
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
MyRepository.php:124:
array (size=2)
  2 =>     <--- Not sorted
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
  1 =>     <--- Not sorted
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
MyRepository.php:124:
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 4
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
MyRepository.php:124:
array (size=2)
  1 =>      <--- Sorted
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 4
  2 =>      <--- Sorted
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 2
```

Comment: what if you use `->values()` on the collection, would that help?

Comment: Just now, I tried values() however, it changed the keys(2,1) to array indices(0,1).

Comment: And no sorting happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$thisCollection = $thisCollection->toArray();
$thisCollection = ksort($thisCollection);
$thisCollection = collect($thisCollection);
```

the idea is to turn your collection to array, then ksort it, then return back the array to collection with collect() helper.

Comment: $thisCollection = ksort($thisCollection); <--- returned boolean

Comment: you are welcome. i dont know if your $thisCollection is an array or a collection